Create databricks external_location on storage account without any containers? i have to specify in the url the container name but there isnt any
I'm using terraform to create databricks external location on a storage account that has no containers, will be added dynamically later. My issue is that i have to specifiy a container name in the url, how can i overcome this?
 resource "databricks_external_location" "external_location" {
  url  = format("abfss://%s@%s.dfs.core.windows.net", "root",    data.azurerm_storage_account.storage.name).

I keep getting
Error: cannot create external location: Failed to access cloud storage: [InvalidUriAuthorityException] () exceptionTraceId=
I had other external locations that had storage accounts with containers, it worked fine but that one isnt getting created

Adding "root" in place of a container is throwing "cannot access cloud storage error when I tried in my environment." If you wanted to add container values dynamically later, create a dummy container from portal and provide that value with the variable file as shown below. Modify the values once your container values are set.
Note: Without providing a container details, it is not exactly possible to create a databricks external location.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    databricks = {
      source = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "1.45.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "databricks" {
 host = "adbxxxx9.19.azuredatabricks.net"
 token = "dapiab41dfbd4bd0308b068adf8105ee81cb-3"
}
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
provider "null" {
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example"{
 name = "databricks-rg-mydbws-6zhmu4f6zorry"
}
data "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name = "dbstoragehz3mni437i3au"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name  
}
resource "azurerm_databricks_access_connector" "ext_access_connector" {
  name                = "accesstsor"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ext_storage" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_databricks_access_connector.ext_access_connector.identity[0].principal_id
}
resource "databricks_storage_credential" "external" {
  name = "mycreds"
  azure_managed_identity {
    access_connector_id = azurerm_databricks_access_connector.ext_access_connector.id
  }
  comment = "Managed by TF"
}

resource "databricks_external_location" "some" {
  name = azurerm_databricks_access_connector.ext_access_connector.name
  url = format("abfss://%s@%s.dfs.core.windows.net/",var.emptycontainer,data.azurerm_storage_account.example.name)
  credential_name = databricks_storage_credential.external.id
  comment         = "Managed by TF"
}

var.tf:
variable "emptycontainer"{
type = string
default = "<ContainerName>"
}

You can also use a null_resource to create a dummy container with the below code format.
resource "null_resource" "dummy" {
  triggers  = {
    type = "always"
} 

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az storage container create --name <containername> --account-name ${data.azurerm_storage_account.example.name} --resource-group ${data.azurerm_storage_account.example.resource_group_name}"
  }
}

Deployment succeeded:


Reference: Blog
